# Sending email using C#

Tags: c#, email, smtp

Hello I'm trying to send an email from and @gmail account to the same gmail account(or other) using C# but I'm having problem authenticating. First solution I tried after looking some posts here was that I needed to turn on "LEss secure apps" on the google account, but goolge no longer suports that option, so my second solution was to create an app password and use the app password in place of the account password(string password = "appPassword"). The code runs, no error but also doens't send the email. Matter of fact write either the try or catch message output.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace EmailSender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string toEmail = "elmer.drasken@gmail.com";
            string fromEmail = "john.strong.light@gmail.com";
            string password = "evtccjtekexyxskr";
            string subject = "Test Email";
            string body = "This is a test email.";

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail, password);

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail, subject, body);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            // Attach the log file
            string attachmentPath = @"C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\CPUMemoryMonitor\errorLog\Logs\errorlog.txt";
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
            message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
                Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow you really need to sort your formatting out. Have you tried runnig this line by line in the debugger?

Comment: Reading the code I think you are having a XY problem. Why do you attach a "error log file" to a mail when you can send the error data to your own service in a REST?

Comment: The debugger is a very useful tool especially for tracing lines that are throwing exceptions.

Comment: If the code does not throw any exceptions to the message box and also does not send an email then the code is failing silently.

Comment: Did you read the "Important remarks" section in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient)? "We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development"